# An algebraic equation with integer part function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the following equation with respect to $x$:

$$m=⌊x⌋+⌊a⌋$$

where $m$ is a positive integer and $a$ is a positive real number.

My **question** is how to obtain the unknown $x$. Here $⌊x⌋$ is the integer part of $x$.

Comment: Firstly, if $a$ is an integer, then $\lfloor{a}\rfloor=a$.

Comment: @quasi: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: Are $m,a$ regarded as given?

Comment: @quasi: Yes. They are given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $m,a$ are regarded as given . . .

Then solving for $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ yields
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=m-\lfloor{a}\rfloor$$
hence, $x$ can be any real number in the interval $[m-\lfloor{a}\rfloor,m-\lfloor{a}\rfloor+1)$.

Comment: Is there a rule that $\lfloor{x+y}\rfloor =\lfloor{x}\rfloor + \lfloor{y}\rfloor$ ?

Comment: @Fareed AF: No, there is no such rule. What _is_ true is that $\lfloor{x+y}\rfloor$ is equal to _either_ $\lfloor{x}\rfloor + \lfloor{y}\rfloor$ _or_  $\lfloor{x}\rfloor + \lfloor{y}\rfloor+1$. For example, try $x=y=1/2$.